# Parsing JSON-Request with Flask-REST API, Receiving "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable" for simple String-Object

Tags: python, json, rest, dictionary, flask

I have following code, sending a request to a WebService written in Flask:

```
ts_list = [3, 4]
meta_list = [1, 2]
if meta_list :
    json_lof_list = json.dumps(meta_list)
    lof_check = "LOF"
else:
    lof_check = "No"
if ts_list:
    ts_check = "TS"
else:
    ts_check = "No"
json_lof = json.dumps(lof_check)
json_ts = json.dumps(ts_check)

payload =  {

        "apikey": "tldr12345" ,

        "UseLOF" : json_lof ,

        "tables_lof" : json_lof_list ,

        "UseTS" : json_ts ,

        "table_ts" : "TsInput"
        }


body = str.encode(json.dumps(payload))
headers = { "Content-Type":"application/json"}
request = urllib.request.Request("http://127.0.0.1:5000/json-example-Influx", body, headers)
```

In the Flask-WebApp the request is parsed and the arguments are handled as following:

```
req_data = request.get_json() #parse request
authkey = req_data['apikey'] 
if authkey == key: #check if key matches authentication
    lof_check = json.loads(req_data['UseLOF'])
    if lof_check == "LOF":
        lof_tables = req_data["tables_lof"]
        lof_tables = json.loads(lof_tables)
    check_ts = json.loads(req_data("UseTS"))
```

For the first objects parsing works perfectly fine, but when the code gets to check_ts I receive an error:

```
    check_ts =  json.loads(req_data("UseTS"))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Acutally the Object contains only a simple String and when I print the body before sending the request I receive this:

```
b'{"apikey": "tldr12345", "UseLOF": "\\"LOF\\"", "tables_lof": "[1, 2]", "UseTS": "\\"TS\\"", "table_ts": "TsInput"}'
```

How can I access the value of "UseTS" in my Flask-WebService and what is it about this object that causes the error, whereas the other objects are handled without any problems?

Comment: Without studying the program: looks like you need square brackets here: `req_data["UseTS"]`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Sometimes it feels very hard not to see the wood for the trees.